# Discord.py. Как получить числовой id реакции и как повесить реакцию на сообщения бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

После всего выше перечисленного хотелось бы узнать как выводить сообщение после того как пользователь нажал на саму реакцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ID реакции не существует, но существует ID эмодзи:

```
print(reaction.emoji.id)
```

2. Чтобы повесить реакцию на сообщение, для начала получи объект этого сообщения, а затем уже используй метод add_reaction():

```
message = await ctx.send("Hi!")
# Или:
message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)

# emoji может быть объектом следующих классов: Emoji, Reaction, PartialEmoji, str
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

3. Если тебе нужно, чтобы после нажатия реакции писалось сообщение, используй событие "on_raw_reaction_add":

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    await channel.send("Message")
```